# Missing Expression for the Oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I am trying to run this query but I am getting a **Missing Expression error**.

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by 'rownum') row_num1,
         * 
  FROM   A
  WHERE  refresh_date = (
           SELECT max(refresh_date)
           FROM   A 
           WHERE  upper(flaw_table_name) = upper('B')
         )
)
WHERE row_num1 >= 1
AND   row_num1 <=20
```

Can you please help me out, where I am getting wrong.

Comment: seems comma is missing  between ROW_NUMBER  and OVER() select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by 'rownum'

Comment: I tried adding the comma between ROW_NUMBER and OVER() but getting the error "Missing window specification for this function "

Comment: SELECT * from (select ROW_NUMBER(), OVER(order by 'rownum') row_num1,* from A where refresh_date =  (Select max(refresh_date) from A where upper(flaw_table_name) = upper('B') )) where row_num1>= 1 and row_num1<=20 but getting an error Missing window specification for this function

Comment: `order by 'rownum'` makes no sense. You are sorting on a **constant** value. It's the same as `order by 42`. You can use `row_number() over ()` if you don't care about the numbers generated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to add an alias, you cannot use * without a name if you're using other colnames or functions too

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT row_number() over(ORDER BY 'rownum') row_num1,
               t.*
          FROM a  t
         WHERE refresh_date =
               (SELECT MAX(refresh_date)
                  FROM a
                 WHERE upper(flaw_table_name) = upper('B')))
 WHERE row_num1 >= 1
   AND row_num1 <= 20
```

Answer (score 2):

select star is in Oracle(?)  not possible to combine with other explicite columns. You need to qualify the star with the alias A in the subquery.

```
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by 'rownum') row_num1,
     A.*
  FROM A
```

This is causing the **Missing Expression error** -  after that you will see other errors

Answer (score 2):

You have a constant in the `order by` clause.  In addition, it is redundant to put `rownum` there in the first place.  Just use `rownum`.

I think you want:

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM   A
WHERE refresh_date = (SELECT max(refresh_date)
                       FROM A 
                       WHERE upper(flaw_table_name) = upper('B')
                      ) AND
      rownum between 1 and 20;
```

The subquery is not necessary and Oracle is smart enough to evaluate the `rownum` expression *after* the other conditions in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from (
          select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by 'rownum') row_num1, * from A 
          where refresh_date =  ( Select max(refresh_date) 
                                  from A 
                                  where upper(flaw_table_name) = upper('B') 
                                )
          ) where row_num1>= 1 and row_num1<=20
```

replace last where clause  with **"and"**  as where is already present in query

Comment: no its not working ..tried the above code.. getting the same error as missing expression for this function